# How to create s button, that should stay visible even if I am scrolling the page down?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have created a button in HTML. But when I scroll down the page button also goes up. I want to create a button which should be stay floating in the air on my screen even I am scrolling the page.

I wrote this code for creating button

```
<div id ="myDiv">
    <button type="button" onclick="previous()">Previous Month</button>
</div>
```

Comment: <div id ="myDiv"><button type="button" onclick="previous()">Previous Month</button>

Comment: you can add css property `position:fixed`

Comment: [`position: fixed`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#fixed) documentation.

Comment: As others have said use position:fixed. You'll also need to supply a value for top, bottom, left. or right depending on how you want the button to display

Comment: What have you tried so far? You haven't posted any of the CSS attempts

Answer (score 5):

You can just use `position: fixed`. I just provided a sample snippet, go through it.

```css
#myDiv{
  position: fixed;
  left: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div id ="myDiv">
    <button type="button" onclick="previous()">Previous Month</button>
</div>
<div> Jan </div>
<div> Feb </div>
<div> Mar </div>
<div> Apr </div>
<div> May </div>
<div> Jun </div>
<div> Jul </div>
<div> Aug </div>
<div> Sep </div>
<div> Oct </div>
<div> Nov </div>
<div> Dec </div>
<div> Jan </div>
<div> Feb </div>
<div> Mar </div>
<div> Apr </div>
<div> May </div>
<div> Jun </div>
<div> Jul </div>
<div> Aug </div>
<div> Sep </div>
<div> Oct </div>
<div> Nov </div>
<div> Dec </div>
```

Comment: I suggest using the `top`, `right`, `bottom` and `left` properties to specify offsets for elements that are positioned absolutely. Margins should only be used in certain situations.

Answer (score 1):

If you need the button always be on the same position (regarding your screen, not container) - use `position: fixed`.
Get details here https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp

Comment: no, look I have an HTML page with a button and with some javascript. that page is giving me a big list of months. when i scroll down to see all months, and if i want to go to next page all i have to do is to go up all the way and press the button. so i want a button that should scroll so i don't have to go back to top

Comment: @Aqil Yes, the `position` of this button then has to be set to `fixed`.

Comment: Probably, you mean the situation when you need the button fixed (when scrolling), but only within parent block. Am I right?

Comment: @Aqil In this way you can use `position: sticky`. But, it's not supported in all browser, check it - https://caniuse.com/#search=sticky